# Alamofire: Request Timeout on a specific URL & device

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

We're experiencing this weird error. We're receiving a "Request Timed Out" error on a specific base URL that we're using whereas another base URL is working.

[image]

I suspect there is something with that specific base URL. But I might be missing something on my end.

Also, this happens on an actual device only, and it works using a simulator. We're also using a VPN (whereas the old base URL also works)

Comment: Is it possible that the URL that doesnt work is http, where the one that works is https?
If so, you will need to set app transport security settings in your info.plist.
If not, then it is a bit difficult to diagnose. Do they both work from a testing tool like Postman?

Comment: Hi, @James. We already set the app NSAppTransportSecurity to true, and the old base URL uses HTTP:// also. It also works on Postman and on the simulator.

Comment: test you can ping base url(host) if can’t find problem.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Turns out the base URL was the issue. We ended up using a different base URL.